# Dictionary order and least upper bound for linear continuum

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to figure out why does the set $L=\mathbb{Z_+} \times [0,1)$ with dictionary order has the least upper bound property? I say this is the counter example: Suppose $[5,1)<[9,1)$ that is we look at the two sets $[a,1)$ and $[b,1)$ such that $a,b \in \mathbb{Z_+}$, we can never find a least upper bound for those sets because the set of positive integers is not bounded.

Is my reasoning correct and the definition of dictionary order doesn't say anything if the second co-ordinates are equal

Comment: What do you mean by $[5,1)$ and $[9,1)$? These notations don’t make sense.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: They are intervals. Like $L=\{[a,b) | a\in \mathbb{Z_+}$ and $b \in [0,1)\}$

Comment: That is not what $L$ is. Elements of $L$ are ordered pairs $\langle n,x\rangle$, where $n$ is a positive integer, and $x\in[0,1)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Could you please elaborate? But what does those element represent?

Comment: I don’t know what there is to elaborate: $L$ is a Cartesian product of two sets, so its elements are ordered pairs whose first components are from the first set, and whose second components are from the second set. That’s just definition.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I see! But still the same argument will hold true for there not being a least upper bound because you can never bound the first co-ordinate

Comment: The least upper bound property says that if a set has an upper bound, then it has a least upper bound; it does not say that every set has a least upper bound. That is in fact the case for $L$. As a matter of fact, $L$ is order-isomorphic to the non-negative reals, which you know have the least upper bound property.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I am  just trying to work with the definitions. Would it possible to argue for least upper bound in terms of its def?

Comment: Yes, but first you have to understand the structure of $L$ and the lexicographic order on $L$. I’m writing up an explanation of why $L$ has the lub property, but it will take a few minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’ll write $\preceq$ for the lexicographic order on $L$. Suppose that $A$ is a non-empty subset of $L$ that is bounded above by some $\langle m,y\rangle\in L$. Let $N=\{n\in\Bbb Z_+:\langle n,0\rangle\text{ is an upper bound for }A\}$; $\langle m,y\rangle\prec\langle m+1,0\rangle$, so $\langle m+1,0\rangle$ is an upper bound for $A$, $m+1\in N$, and therefore $N\ne\varnothing$. Thus, $N$ is a non-empty set of positive integers and has a least element $n_0$.

If $\langle n_0,0\rangle\in A$, then clearly $\langle n_0,0\rangle=\max A$, so $\langle n_0,0\rangle$ is the least upper bound for $A$. If $\langle n_0,0\rangle\notin A$, let $$S=\{x\in[0,1):\langle n_0-1,x\rangle\in A\}\;;$$ $n_0-1\notin N$, so $\langle n_0-1,0\rangle$ is not an upper bound for $A$, and there is therefore an $x\in(0,1)$ such that $\langle n_0-1,x\rangle\in A$, so $S\ne\varnothing$. $S$ is a bounded subset of $\Bbb R$, so it has a least upper bound $s_0$. To finish the argument, just show that $\langle n_0-1,s_0\rangle$ is the least upper bound of $A$ in $L$.

Comment: Why does $<n_0, 0>=$max $A$? Isn't this possible:
$<n_0, 0> \preceq <n_0, x>$ where $x\in (0,1)$

Comment: @RutherfordMark: $\langle n_0,0\rangle$ is an upper bound for $A$, so no element of $A$ is strictly greater than $\langle n_0,0\rangle$. If $\langle n_0,0\rangle$ is actually in $A$, then it must be the largest element of $A$.